# Tracking Robot position using Marker

Tags: ros, rviz, marker, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am using ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04.
I am working on a RVIZ Marker program to track "\AMCL_Pose" parameter and visualize in RVIZ.
The code I have written is as follows

```
"""
The following program is used to display the real pose positions taken by the
robot in rviz.
References:
1.https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/88812/visualization_msgs.msg.Marker
"""

import rospy
from visualization_msgs.msg import Marker
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseWithCovarianceStamped,Point

def callback(data):
    add_point = Point()
    add_point.x = data.pose.pose.position.x
    add_point.y = data.pose.pose.position.y
    add_point.z = 0
    rospy.loginfo('Publishing Marker Point')
    marker.points.append(add_point)
    # Publish the Marker
    pub_point.publish(marker)
    rospy.sleep(5)


marker = Marker()
marker.header.frame_id = "/map"
marker.type = marker.LINE_STRIP
marker.action = marker.ADD

# marker scale
marker.scale.x = 0.03
marker.scale.y = 0.03
marker.scale.z = 0.03

# marker color
marker.color.a = 1.0
marker.color.r = 1.0
marker.color.g = 0.0
marker.color.b = 0.0

# marker orientaiton
marker.pose.orientation.x = 0.0
marker.pose.orientation.y = 0.0
marker.pose.orientation.z = 0.0
marker.pose.orientation.w = 1.0
"""
# marker position
marker.pose.position.x = 0.0
marker.pose.position.y = 0.0
marker.pose.position.z = 0.0
"""
# marker line points
marker.points = []
rospy.loginfo('Marker created')

rospy.init_node('position_tracker')

pub_point = rospy.Publisher('realpoints_marker', Marker, queue_size=1)
print "Publisher created...."

rospy.Subscriber("/amcl_pose",PoseWithCovarianceStamped, callback)
print "Subcriber created...."
rospy.spin()
```

I get the following result
[image: image description]

The issue is that the length and orientation of the line are not proper.
The robot has moved over 20 meters but in rviz it showing only 5 meters.

How to resolve this issue ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335299/tracking-robot-position-using-marker/) by [BV_Pradeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/44054/bv_pradeep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2019-10-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fixed the issue by removing the sleep time in the publisher.

---

Originally posted by [BV_Pradeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/44054/bv_pradeep/) with karma: 46 on 2020-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1